# Bounded below to imply the other sequence is bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose I proved that $a_n=(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$ has a tail that is bounded below. Show that $b_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ has a bounded above tail.

My attempt: Suppose $(1-\frac{1}{n})^n \geq m$ $\forall n >N$ then $(1-\frac{1}{n})^{-n} \leq m^{-1}$ substitute $r=-n$ will give $(1+\frac{1}{r})^{r} \leq m^{-1}$. However, wouldn't this only work for $r<N$ so I think this doesn't work?

Comment: Hint: $b_n = (1/a_{n+1}) \cdot n/(n+1)$.

Comment: I don't think this identity holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_nb_n=(1-\frac 1 {n^{2}})^{n} \leq 1$. Hence, $a_n \geq a$ ($a>0$) implies $b_n \leq \frac 1 a$.